# Geometry Nodes - Align Monkey head to random placed Bodies

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to get rotation of instances?
I want to place monkey head on bodies with proper alignment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Basically, you can just use the position of your instances as the position, but I'm guessing you'll want to put the head on the shoulder as well. Further, I suspect that the instances are different, which should change this position as well. So it all kind of depends on your construction. Maybe it would be good if you share your blend file with us, so we can better understand how you built this: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @quellenform, file was attached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need *Geometry Nodes* here (even if I think in principle that you can almost always use them).

Here you could work with constraints.

Add the constraint *Copy Location* and *Copy Rotation* to the heads, and use the respective body as *Target*.

[image]

But if you really want to use *geometry nodes*, here's how you can solve it:

[image]

Here I simply instantiate the heads at a line (which consists of exactly one point, and is created at the local zero point).

Before that I use the node `Transform`, so that the head remains a little positionable.

The head automatically inherits the rotation from the rotation of the body.

[image]

---

**Update:**

You mentioned in your comment: *"...and just imagine, that we have thousands of these bodies"*.

...is 8K enough? or should it be 2M? ...I think it depends on your machine.

Here is a solution where any number of bodies can be combined with any number of heads:

[image]

First, here I instantiate the bodies from a collection. Of course you can also use a single object. The bodies and heads themselves have no further modifiers or constraints attached in this setup.

Next, I take the instances, and convert them back to points for instantiating the heads.

this way you can cascade or change it as you need.

[image]

Comment: Thanx for the answer! Yeah, second method with copying geometry node modifiers to all bodies objects is pretty logical, but what if I want to achieve it with Collection Info Node, without copying geometry node modifier to all body instances

...and just imagine, that we have thousands of these bodies
so we can't just add constraints to all of them and easily tweak

Comment: i'm starting thinking, that copying geometry nodes modifier is the only option and the only supported and desired logic by developers, but sadly it's not that handy, that how i want it to be... i mean, to rule all of them from one place

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll take another look. If I understand you correctly, you want to randomly combine and distribute the bodies and heads from a collection, right?

Comment: no, it's not about randomness, i just want to place the head to all bodies in the collection with proper alignment

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow ...updated the answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: oh, no no, man, i really appreciate your attention to my quastion, but you get it wrong ;~;
by "thouthands bodies" i mean *already places* instances in scene.
So the task is: you already have many instances places in the model with their rotations, and you need to place monkey head to all of them with propper alignment
I will accept your answer as solved, because i think there is olny one way to do it: copying modifier to all instances by your hands. Thanx again!

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow OK, you are right: *Geometry Nodes* can of course only work if they are added as modifiers. But you could use Python to copy the modifiers to other objects, then you would save yourself the manual copying. That would be an interesting further question (if it hasn't already been answered here).